# Search in uisearchbar from different view/class

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I can search with UISearchbar if UISearchbar and searchDisplayController is in the same view.

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

Now, I have UISearchbar in header view and I need to show result in other view controller as shown in this picture. How can I set up uisearchbar with uisearchdisplaycontroller from different view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `searchResultsDataSource` and `searchResultsDelegate` to the UITableView in the other view.